# Looking for datasheet of Toshiba T2742 integrated circuit

Tags: sensor, automotive, inductance, proximity-sensor, inductance-measurement

I'm looking for datasheet for Toshiba T2742 Integrated circuit. IC is used in old car with tachometer sensor, probably as AFE (Analog Front End). Tachometer sensor is a inductance proximity sensor, but not like today's sensors with OC output, I'm 99% sure it is just a coil (i've made some measurements, results below). I need to make new circuit for this sensor (consisting with oscillator, demodulator and comparator OR with other modern and available IC), and reverse engineering could be very helpful.

Coil measurements using few frequencies:

1. f = 1kHz, L = 674mH, R = 2.1k
2. f = 7kHz, L = 460mH, R = 11k, Y = 43uS, Q = 1.9
3. f = 26kHz, L = 310mH, R = 37.6k, Y = 15.8uS, Q = 1.35
4. f = 70kHz, L = 80mH, R = 195.5k, Y = 5uS, Q = 0.18
5. simple resistance measurement: 1.5k

Thanks a lot for any help and suggestions.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any datasheets online, but I suspect it's a [variable reluctance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_reluctance_sensor) sensor signal conditioning IC. You can find other ICs of that type from various sources, such as the [LM1815](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1815.pdf) and the [MAX992x](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max9924-max9927.pdf) series, or the [LM2907](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2907-n.pdf) (Sparkfun has a board with the latter, which is intended for tachometer usage). Image from the LM2907 datasheet:

[image]

The sensor consists of a coil, a permanent magnet and a rotating gear-like part.

The voltage output of the coil varies greatly with speed so the analog front end has to be designed to accomodate that variation and respond only to the frequency.

The SIP package was popular with Japanese makers of simple linear ICs in the 1990s or thereabouts since they had layout and density advantages on cheap single-sided boards. They never really caught on outside Japan and SMT came along shortly thereafter.

Comment: Thanks, I think it could be helpful. I ordered similar IC (LM2917) and i will test it soon. But because LM2907/2917 is frequency to voltage converter (f/U) i'm not sure if that magnetic sensor on diagram is like modern one - with open collector output. I will test it and post some results :-)